# Get dynamic json content with file_get_contents() from URL

Tags: php, json, laravel

I want to get dynamic json content with `file_get_contents('http://ip-api.com/json/')`.

If I turn on the VPN and go to URL, I get the dynamic content but If I use the URL in `file_get_contents()` while VPN is still on, I see the same old content i.e. Changing the location doesn't change the content retrieved by `file_get_contents('http://ip-api.com/json/')`

Comment: This may be a stupid answer, but where are you turning the VPN on? Is it on the machine that processess the PHP script (server), or is it on the device requesting the PHP script (i.e. your mobile phone)?

Comment: The VPN needs to be turned on on the machine which is executing the PHP. Otherwise the file_get_content request will be routed via the normal route for that machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the problem you're facing is that you're turning on VPN from the device that requests the PHP script, not on the machine executing it. This way ip-api.com just responds data for the IP that is doing the request (PHP server).
As per their documentation (https://ip-api.com/docs/api:json), you can request JSON for a specific IP. To achieve getting information about IP address from which the PHP script is being called (i.e. your mobile phone), you can use endpoint http://ip-api.com/json/1.2.3.4.
To get where you probably want to be, do the following:

```
file_get_contents('http://ip-api.com/json/' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
```

The REMOTE_ADDR key in $_SERVER variable contains the IP address of the requestor.